# Selenium with Metamask for OpenSea.io

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, metamask, opensea

I am trying to automate some interactions with OpenSea.io.

Using Selenium with a Metamask wallet I was able to automate specific actions around collections and everything was working as intended for several weeks approximately 1 year ago.

After having paused the project for a while, I came back to working on it these past few days.
With minimal changes around Selenium's driver and how that gets initialized, the main issue I am having is actually being able to login to OpenSea.io.

As it worked in the past, the logic step was only partly automated.
Specifically, I launch a Chrome session to the OpenSea.io website with Selenium, having the Metamask plug-in attached, and I do all of the required actions manually (import wallet in Metamask, connect wallet in OpenSea.io).

Again, this worked without any issues previously.
Currently, when attempting to 'Connect Wallet' in OpenSea.io I am getting the following error (in a browser toast message):

```
Relay request for `walletMultiQuery` failed by the following reasons: 
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en-US"> <head> <title>Access denied</title> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> 
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/errors.css" media="screen" /> 
<script> (function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify)
{...
```

While generic, the error does clearly suggest a denial of access.

Has anything changed on the OpenSea.io side to prevent such interactions?
As mentioned, the actual actions are done manually, so timing and such would not be a problem.

Would it be something to do with the Selenium setup? Maybe cookies?

Are there any currently viable workarounds for this?

Comment: Okay, take a step back for a second, using an new ingognito browser session, can you complete your entire script and all steps you want it to do 100% manually? If that works then you can safely focus on fixing your script.

Comment: I thought about testing that, but I am not sure how you can use the Metamask plug-in with Incognito mode.

Comment: If you can't use a plugin in Incognito, just open a normal browser session, and completly clear your broswer cache. Typically `Ctrl + F5`

Comment: Authenticating from scratch with a non-Selenium session works with no issues.